# 1694 (HY000): Cannot modify @@session.sql_log_bin inside a transaction

Tags: python, mysql, rds

I am trying to call mysql.rds_set_configuration RDS stored procedure from a python client, however I am ending up with subjected ERROR

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                 user = app_conf.rds_user,
                 password = app_conf.rds_password,
                 host = master_db
                 )
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     cursor.callproc**('mysql.rds_set_configuration', ['binlog retention hours', 12 ])**
          for result in cursor.stored_results():
            print(result.fetchall())
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
          print("Failed to execute stored procedure: {}".format(error))
        finally:
          if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

it fails with

```
Failed to execute stored procedure: 1694 (HY000): Cannot modify @@session.sql_log_bin inside a transaction
MySQL connection is closed
```

If I login to RDS and execute this stored procedure there is no issue.

I also tried using python library pymysql, however same issue.

mysql version is

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                 |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.26                |
| protocol_version        | 10                    |
| slave_type_conversions  |                       |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 |
| version                 | 5.7.26-log            |
| version_comment         | Source distribution   |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                 |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Kindly suggest !!!

Answer (score 2):

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
             user = app_conf.rds_user,
             database='mysql',
             password = app_conf.rds_password,
             host = master_db,
             autocommit = True
```

Setting autocommit to true help me resolve this issue